# Howto get standard system directories with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, platform-independent

Is there a Python(3) way to get the directories for configration (e.g. `/etc`), log-files, home-dir, etc for the current system (Linux, Windows, ...).

I couldn't find something like this in the os-Package.

Comment: There isn't any such method in other languages either. FHS & XDG are the closest you get to a standard but it is limited to UNIX systems. Windows marches to their own beat.

Comment: I think there are a lot of platform-independend gui-toolkits (Qt, ...) which provide thinks like that. Of course I would prefere a independed solution. Python offer so much platform-independed stuff so I thought there is a Python-solution for this, too.